# How do I validate and access EV properties of a EV Certificate?

Tags: c#, cryptography, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I'd like to determine if a given x509 Certificate is an EV cert using C#. Since there are no properties available to me in the .NET API and I'm not sure where to get more information on this standard, I'm a bit stuck.

Does anyone have the answer, or know where I should start looking inside the binary blob?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EV certificate is distinguished by special certificate policy (that's a certificate extension), so by reading this extension you can recognize EV certificate. Complete list of EV policy identifiers can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate#Extended_Validation_certificate_identification).